# The number of injective functions

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of injective functions (from finite set to finite set):

$$
f:\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} \rightarrow \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}
$$

with the following property:
$$
f(i) \neq f(j)+1\  \text{  for all  } \ 1\leq i < j \leq 7.
$$

Help me with mathematical decision (I can count this number on computer). Thank you.

Comment: The total number of injective functions is $\frac{9!}{2!}$ because there are $9$ choices for $f(1)$, $8$ for $f(2)$, etc. Injecting (seems like a good choice of word) the required property makes it much harder.  Maybe inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: If I found the answer, what should I do? Can I just delete this question?

Comment: Idea of decision is - $f:\{ 1,..,n \} \rightarrow \{ 1,..,n+2 \}$. Every "Injecting" divide set $\{ 1,..,n+2 \}$ into $3$ subsets. So we can placed $n$ numbers at any of this three subsets by $3^n$ ways.

Comment: If you find the answer, you are encouraged to write it up as an answer and accept it.